# SQLite Xamarin PCL

Tags: database, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite.net

I am developing an App in Xamarin type PCL, for my DB structure, I want to use SQLite, but I have the following doubts ...

1. When entering a record in my DB, it takes the ID = 0, in my data model use

   ```
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        Public int ViolationID {get; set; }
   ```

And still, I enter the registry at zero, I do not know I'm doing wrong ... or is this a bug in the SQLite.NET-PCL package?

2. How can I verify that these records are actually being entered? I have in my code

   ```
   public class DataAccess : IDisposable
   {
       private SQLiteConnection connection;

       public DataAccess()
       {
           var entity = DependencyService.Get<IEntity>();
           connection = new SQLiteConnection(entity.Plataforma, System.IO.Path.Combine(entity.DirectorioBD, "Infraccions.db3"));
           connection.CreateTable<Infraccion>();
       }

       public void InsertInfraccion(Infraccion infraccion)
       {
           connection.Insert(infraccion);
       }

       public void UpdateInfraccion(Infraccion infraccion)
       {
           connection.Update(infraccion);
       }

       public Infraccion GetInfraccion(int InfraccionID)
       {
           return connection.Table<Infraccion>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.InfraccionID == InfraccionID);
       }

       public List<Infraccion> GetInfraccions()
       {
           return connection.Table<Infraccion>().OrderBy(c => c.MotivoID).ToList();
       }

       public void DeleteInfraccion(Infraccion infraccion)
       {
           connection.Delete(infraccion);
       }

       public void Dispose()
       {
           connection.Dispose();
       }
   }
   ```

Should I create a table called Infraccions.db3 on my phone?

Thank you for your comments...

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that all new records have an ID of 0 and overwrite the existing record in the database?

If so, then this is how SQLite works - for int columns 0 is a valid value, so when the ID is 0 it will overwrite the record, instead of incrementing the value.

The correct way to use int primary keys is to define your primary key as a nullable int, that way the value for a new record is null, which will be updated to the next available id:

```
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
public int? ViolationID {get; set; }
```

Essentially change `int` to `int?`.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) When entering a record in my DB, it takes the ID = 0, in my data
>   model use

You are using primary key and auto increment in your model that's means you are not able to enter 0 manually in the primary field and it takes automatically next value in this field.

> 2) How can I verify that these records are actually being entered?

You can get DB file path when you create your database and you can able to open and see that data.

```
(System.IO.Path.Combine(entity.DirectorioBD, "Infraccions.db3") )
```

There are many browser plugins to access the sqllite database.

Comment: I can not find the .db3 file, are you creating it in a hidden way? If so ... how do I get it for public mode? Any help for me

Comment: Which phone are you using?

Comment: Alcatel Pixi 4 @Ziyad